# Redis error : Timeout performing EVAL (5000ms) with asp.net session state

Tags: asp.net, session, redis, session-state, stackexchange.redis

Getting frequent issues as below after migrating session state to redis

Timeout performing EVAL(5000ms), inst: 0,qs:5,in:65536,serverEndpoint: Unspecified/xxxxx, mgr 10 of 10 available, clientName:xxxx, IOCP:(Busy=0,Free=200,Min=100,Max=200),WORKER:(Busy=11,Free=189,Min=100,Max=200), v:2.0.519.65453

The inst, qs, in, busy, free value changes with each error.
We are using on prem Redis instance with Tier 1-1GB and no replication memory allocated.
With each person logging in we see 2 keys added(Internal, Data) and our data size overall is 2MB each. We have 70 keys approx. Keys are very small but 3 have very big values which makes up approx 1.7MB of 2 of which 1 itself may be of 1MB and other 2 make up. 7MB and rest 67 keys/values 0.3 mb
I have seen this issue generally occurs when trying to fetch one of those 3 bigger key values.
Is there any restriction in value size of a key?
Or could it be some other issue?

Comment: This helped me, I did not have targetFramework in my httpRuntime tag in my web.config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/993854/all-redis-commands-timing-out-when-using-azure-cac.html